# How to store different timestamps of packets in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, networking, omnet++

I am new in OMNeT++. I am doing a simple simulation where a client sends some packets to a server. I want, for instance, store the timestamp of the first packet sent, and later, I want store the timestamp of the tenth package sent. I would want to be able to store those two timestamps in two variables, `timestamp_of_first_packet` and `timestamp_of_last_packet`, kind of like

```
packets_sent = 1
cPacket* testPacket = new cPacket();
double timestamp_of_first_packet = testPacket->getTimestamp().dbl();
packets_sent++;
... 
double timestamp_of_last_packet = testPacket->getTimestamp().dbl();
```

The aim is to calculate a time interval between the two packets, with this formula:

```
double time_interval = timestamp_of_last_packet - timestamp_of_first_packet;
```

I know that this method is wrong, because both variables store the same value. 
How I can store both timestamps correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current simulation time by calling simTime(). If you want some time to pass in your simulation, have your module schedule an event to itself (using scheduleAt). Remember your module is written in C++, so you can use all its features (like member variables) to write clean code.

Comment: Yes, I know that; but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: I apologize. Can you rephrase your question to help understand it?

Comment: OK. I know that simTime() gives me the current simulation time. I know how to use scheduleAt() too. That isn't the problem. Let's assume that I am sending the first packet at 1.0 s, the second one at 1.5 s, and so on until the tenth one (the last one) at 5.5 s. (i.d., one interval between packets of 0.5 s). How I can calculate the time interval between the tenth packet and the first packet using their timestamps? Must I use another method? In this I am disoriented. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you send the first packet, store the current simulation time, e.g., this->t1 = simTime() assuming t1 is a member of your class of type simtime_t. Nine events later, store the current simulation time again, this time in, e.g. t2. The time difference can be calculated as t2-t1.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try what you have suggested.